# Telethon event handler stuck looping

Tags: python, python-requests, python-asyncio, telethon

I've been trying to send my client's incoming messages via my bot back to the client. The event handler get stuck in a loop doing so. I'm still new to asynchronous programming and telethon, any feedback or specific reference is highly appreciated. :-)

```
from telethon import TelegramClient, client, events

api_id = xxx
api_hash = 'xxx'

telegram_bot_token = 'xxx'
telegram_chat_id = 'xxx'

bot = TelegramClient('xxx', api_id, api_hash).start(bot_token='xxx')
client = TelegramClient('xxx', api_id, api_hash)

@client.on(events.NewMessage)
async def messaged_by_bot(event):
    await bot.send_message('xxx', event.message.text)

client.start()
client.run_until_disconnected()
```

Comment: well from your code it's expected and has nothing to do with asyncio.
The client gets sent a message and then the bot sends a message to the client which then receives a message etc. You'd need to add some if checks to when you don't want to receive a message

Comment: Whoops, well that's awkward. Thank you very much for taking the time to answer a question like this. Problem solved! Have a great day! :-) @painor